# get rid of string in mysql dump

Tags: php, string, mysql

I created a script to dump my database, the script is working good but there is something I dont like about it.

The (  '  ), How do I dump my tables without having to remove this in every column that it gets fetched?

This part of my script looks like:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($numrows != 0) {
            $insert .= "INSERT INTO {$table} ($fields) VALUES \n";
            while($row = $query->fetch_array())
            {
                $insert .= "(";
                $comma = '';
                foreach($field_list as $field)
                {
                        $row[$field] = preg_replace("#\'#", "", $row[$field]);
                        $insert .= $comma."'".$db->real_escape_string($row[$field])."'";
                        $comma = ', ';
                }
                $insert .= "),\n";


            }
            $insert = substr($insert, 0, -2);
            $insert .= ";\n";
```

I get rid of the string using this code

```
                    $row[$field] = preg_replace("#\'#", "", $row[$field]);
```

and it works, but is there a way to dump the table without having to remove that and the dump to still be able to be imported ?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to me you're only getting the single quotes out of the database because they were inserted there in the first place, so they are part of the data.

Comment: So what's your suggestion ?

Comment: I suggest a few steps: (1) verify that this is happening by browsing the table in a terminal or through a GUI like myPhpAdmin, (2) find original INSERT query which was putting in the quotes and repair it, and (3) create a one-off script to do UPDATE queries on the table(s) in order to repair